Is there any mention of mangalsutra in Vedas?
The parampara of tying mangalsutra is in vogue in Hinduism..But is there any mention of Mangalsutra in Vedas or smritis?

It is mentioned in Laghu Ashvalayana smriti

badhanīyātkanyakākaṇṭhe sūtraṃ maṇisamanvitaṃ।  māṅgalyatantunā'nena
mantreṇa syātsadā satī॥"
[Laghu ashvalAyana Smṛti 5:33]
Meaning:
"In the throat of the bride a thread adorned with a gem should be
tied, by chanting the mantra "mAngalya tantunAnena mama jeevana
hetuna..".

